# How to configure otlp export to Elasticseach APM

Tags: elasticsearch, open-telemetry

I'm trying to implement elasticsearch in a quarkus project, I read that I can do it with opentelemetry, but I can't send the metrics to APM. I am doing with collector-config. Could you help me?

This is the configuration that I am using

docker-compose:

```
services:
  collector:
   image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
   container_name: collector
   hostname: collector
   volumes:
      - ./src/collector-config.yml:/etc/collector-config.yml
   command: [ "--config=/etc/collector-config.yml" ]
   ports:
      - "4317:4317"
```

collector-config.yml:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: collector:4317

exporters:
  logging:
  otlp/elastic:
    endpoint: https://das812391jsadaqwd.apm.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:499
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer 78asd9sadnasd"

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, otlp/elastic]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, otlp/elastic]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, otlp/elastic]
```

I was guided by this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry.html

Comment: Please follow a doc. For example `# Elastic APM server https endpoint without the "https://" prefix`

Comment: Why are you going through a collector and not sending the APM data directly to the APM server? Can you show how you deployed our APM agent in your Quarkus project?

Comment: I was researching and I saw that for a project in Quarkus you have to implement Opentelemetry, I was helping myself from this forum https://discuss.elastic.co/t/does-elastic-apm-support-quarkus/284167